# How to separate words by numbers from a string

Tags: c, string, fgets, words

I have a text file called commands.txt which contains some commands followed by some arguments. Example:

```
STOP 1 2 4
START 5 2 1 8
MOVE
CUT 0 9
```

I want to read every line from this text file and to print something like this

```
STOP: 1 2 3
START: 5 2 1 8
MOVE:
CUT: 0 9
```

I read every line with fgets and then I tried using sscanf but doesn't work.

```
char line[100]   // here I put the line
char command[20] // here I put the command
args[10]         // here I put the arguments



 #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    FILE *f;
char line[100];
char command[20];
int args[10];

f=fopen("commands.txt" ,"rt");
while(!feof(f))
{
fgets(line , 40 , f);
//here i need help
}
fclose(f);
return 0;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: If you are having trouble with `sscanf()` post your code containing `sscanf()`!

Comment: There's no need for `feof()`, just loop until `fgets()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: sscanf( s , "%s %d %d %d %d %d" , command , &args[0] ,&args[1] , &args[2] , &args[3] , &args[4]); The problem is that the number of arguments is not the same for every command

Comment: When posting code to this site, please spend 10 seconds of your time to look at the indention before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/), and use whitespace characters as the delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fscanf()` to read from your file.

If we assume that in your file there is no white spaces (spaces, tab,..) at the end of each line except the newline, then you can use the following code. it's more simple then using `fgets` and split each time

```
int main()

{
    FILE *f;
    char command[20];
    char args[10];
    f=fopen("commands.txt" ,"rt");
    while(fscanf(f, "%s %[^\n]", command, args)>0)
    {
        printf("%s: %s\n", command, args);
    }
}
```